# Getting InvalidOperationException while using my own DialogHost from MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit

Tags: c#, xaml, exception, event-handling, material-design-in-xaml

I'm using the [Material Design library for WPF](https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit) and trying to open a dialogbox when a button is clicked. After calling the `DialogHost.Show(...)` the program breaks with the following message

> Logical tree depth exceeded while traversing the tree. This could indicate a cycle in the tree.

I've tried to understand the stacktrace and why this might be happening but due to limited experience with the library and MVVM architecture can't seem to successfully do so.

Here is stacktrace

```
 StackTrace "
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.FindResourceInTree(FrameworkElement  feStart, FrameworkContentElement fceStart, DependencyProperty dp, Object resourceKey, Object unlinkedParent, Boolean allowDeferredResourceReference, Boolean mustReturnDeferredResourceReference, DependencyObject boundaryElement, InheritanceBehavior& inheritanceBehavior, Object& source)\r\n
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.FindResourceInternal(FrameworkElement fe, FrameworkContentElement fce, DependencyProperty dp, Object resourceKey, Object unlinkedParent, Boolean allowDeferredResourceReference, Boolean mustReturnDeferredResourceReference, DependencyObject boundaryElement, Boolean isImplicitStyleLookup, Object& source)\r\n
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.FindImplicitStyleResource(FrameworkElement fe, Object resourceKey, Object& source)\r\n
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.GetRawValue(DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry& entry)\r\n
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.EvaluateBaseValueCore(DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry)\r\n
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.EvaluateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry newEntry, OperationType operationType)\r\n
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)\r\n
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.InvalidateProperty(DependencyProperty dp, Boolean preserveCurrentValue)\r\n
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.UpdateStyleProperty()\r\n
   at System.Windows.TreeWalkHelper.InvalidateOnTreeChange(FrameworkElement fe, FrameworkContentElement fce, DependencyObject parent, Boolean isAddOperation)\r\n
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ChangeLogicalParent(DependencyObject newParent)\r\n
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.AddLogicalChild(Object child)\r\n
   at System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl.OnContentChanged(Object oldContent, Object newContent)\r\n
   at System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl.OnContentChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)\r\n
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)\r\n
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)\r\n
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)\r\n
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)\r\n
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.InvalidateProperty(DependencyProperty dp, Boolean preserveCurrentValue)\r\n
   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.InvalidateDependents(Style ownerStyle, FrameworkTemplate frameworkTemplate, DependencyObject container, DependencyProperty dp, FrugalStructList 1& dependents, Boolean invalidateOnlyContainer)\r\n
   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.OnTriggerSourcePropertyInvalidated(Style ownerStyle, FrameworkTemplate frameworkTemplate, DependencyObject container, DependencyProperty dp, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs changedArgs, Boolean invalidateOnlyContainer, FrugalStructList 1& triggerSourceRecordFromChildIndex, FrugalMap& propertyTriggersWithActions, Int32 sourceChildIndex)\r\n
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)\r\n
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)\r\n
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)\r\n
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)\r\n
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)\r\n
   at MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.DialogHost.<ShowInternal>d__29.MoveNext() in C:\\projects\\materialdesigninxamltoolkit\\MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf\\DialogHost.cs:line 192\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
   at MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.DialogHost.<Show>d__28.MoveNext() in C:\\projects\\materialdesigninxamltoolkit\\MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf\\DialogHost.cs:line 183\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
   at MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.DialogHost.<Show>d__23.MoveNext() in C:\\projects\\materialdesigninxamltoolkit\\MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf\\DialogHost.cs:line 111\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter 1.GetResult()\r\n
   at SimpleUXApp_ForRizwan.MainWindow.<btn_Action_Click>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\\Users\\Paras\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\SimpleUXApp_ForRizwan\\SimpleUXApp_ForRizwan\\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 99\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_0(Object state)\r\n
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)\r\n
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)\r\n
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()\r\n
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)\r\n
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)\r\n
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)\r\n
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)\r\n
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)\r\n
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()\r\n
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()\r\n
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)\r\n
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)\r\n
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)\r\n
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)\r\n
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)\r\n
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)\r\n
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)\r\n
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)\r\n
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)\r\n
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)\r\n
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)\r\n
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)\r\n
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)\r\n
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()\r\n
   at SimpleUXApp_ForRizwan.App.Main() in C:\\Users\\Paras\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\SimpleUXApp_ForRizwan\\SimpleUXApp_ForRizwan\\obj\\Debug\\App.g.cs:line 0\r\n
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)\r\n
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)\r\n
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()\r\n
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)\r\n
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)\r\n
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)\r\n
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)\r\n
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()"  string
```

and here is the related code

snippet from **MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
    void CredsDialogClosingHandler(object sender, DialogClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        credentials = new UserCreds(txt_Password.SecurePassword);
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private async void btn_Action_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(credentials == null)
        {
            var getCreds = await DialogHost.Show(dialog_about, CredsDialogClosingHandler);
        }
    ...
    }
```

snippet from **MainWindow.xaml**

```
    <materialDesign:DialogHost 
        Name="dialog_about"
        Grid.Row="2"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" CloseOnClickAway="true">
        <materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
            <StackPanel Margin="16">
                <StackPanel Width="350" Height="200">
                    <Label 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                        FontWeight="Medium"
                        FontSize="15"
                        Foreground="{DynamicResource PrimaryHueDarkBrush}"
                        Margin="0,15,0,10">
                        Password please
                    </Label>
                    <PasswordBox 
                        Name="txt_Password"
                        Margin="15,0,0,15" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    </PasswordBox>
                </StackPanel>

                <Button 
                    Name="btn_DialogClose"
                    Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignRaisedButton}"
                    IsDefault="True"
                    Margin="0 8 8 0"
                    MaxWidth="100"
                    Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DialogHost.CloseDialogCommand}"
                    Content="Submit"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
    </materialDesign:DialogHost>
```

**Github Repo**
[Cryption Utility](https://github.com/ParasDPain/Cryption_Utility)

Comment: Hi, are you able to post a sample repo to GitHub?

Comment: @JamesWillock Yep link posted (here it is again: https://github.com/ParasDPain/Cryption_Utility)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things to note.

- DialogHost is a ContentControl, the content being everything for your window, which the *dialog should overlay*.
- When using the DialogHost.Show method you should pass the content for your dialog, not the the DialogHost itself.  **This is the root cause of your cyclical error.**
- Typically you might use DialogHost.Show in a MVVM setup, but you are using code behind.  In this case you can use Routed commands to get your dialog opened, and attached event to callback into your code-behind when the dialog is closed:

> ```
> <Button
>     Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DialogHost.OpenDialogCommand}"
>     materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogClosingAttached="DialogClosing"
> />
> ```

Comment: (And I submitted a PR with these changes: https://github.com/ParasDPain/Cryption_Utility/pull/1 )

Comment: Will this let me call `DialogHost.Show(...)` selectively? As in not call it after a state has been achieved

Comment: To use DialogHost.Show, easiest method is to put the actual content of your dialog in a sperate UserControl, and pass that into the .Show() method.